# Module ScriptToProcess: Is it possible to load functions into module scope preemptively?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I recently discovered the ScriptsToProcess member in module manifests and was trying to explore using it to simplify the organization of my subscripts in modules. Instead of having a separate module subscript that loads all my subscripts, I thought it would be more elegant to reuse my existing manifest file to load the subscripts in the ScriptsToProcess member.

It seems to be working for my enums—at least, I think so. My functions aren't working though, and I haven't gotten the module to run far enough to where it tries to instantiate one of its classes.

#### Example:

```
PS>New-Item -Path test/test.psm1 -Force
PS>cd test
```

**test.psm1**

```
Function testModule {
    callEcho
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function testModule
```

**test.psd1**

```
    PS>New-ModuleManifest -Path .\test.psd1 -RootModule .\test.psm1 -ScriptsToProcess .\subscripts\functions.ps1
    PS>New-Item -Path subscripts/functions.ps1 -Force
```

**functions.ps1**

```
Function writeEcho {
    write-host 'it worked!'
}
Write-Host 'ScriptsToProcess has loaded me'
```

```
PS>Import-Module .\test.psd1 -Force
PS>testModule
callEcho : The term 'callEcho' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

My module doesn't have access to the function.

I assume this is intended, so is there another way to go about it, or do I need to make a separate file which dot sources all my subscripts at the start of the module?

Also, will this behavior also apply to classes?

*PS5.1.14393*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScriptsToProcess` scripts are dot-sourced in the *importer's* scope, and unless that scope happens to be the *global* one,<sup>[1]</sup> your module won't see the definitions.

To dot-source helper scripts in the context of *your module*, place them in a subdirectory named, say, `scripts`, then place the following code in your `RootModule` `.psm1` file:

```
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot/scripts -Filter *.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object { . $_.FullName }
```

Note that unless you expressly export functions defined in these scripts, they'll be visible inside the module only.

---

As for making `enum` and `class` definitions available to the *importer*:

Define them *inside your module* and make the importer import the module via [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/About_Using#module-syntax) rather than via `Import-Module`.

---

<sup>[1] That is, when you run `Import-Module` *directly from the interactive Powershell prompt* (or when you use an equivalent mechanism) - what matters is what scope the *importer* runs in. This is unrelated to *what scope you load the module into*, such as with `Import-Module -Global`</sup>

Comment: hi mklement. What do you mean by "unless that scope happens to be the global one"? I tried `Import-Module -Scope Global`, and it still wasn't visible in the module's scope. Or do you mean defining the function as $global:function ?

Comment: @Blaisem, please see the footnote I've added to the answer.

Comment: Also, @Blaisem: Yes, if you defined your functions as `$global:...`, a module would see it too, but I'd advise against modifying the global scope explicitly - it may affect other code too.